# Can't catch graphQL Error. Keep to showing Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, mutation

When I get GraphQL error, I want to show some modal or message.
Of course, I got error console by adding like this.

```
  const [submitVoting, { loading, error}] = useMutation(mutationQuery);
```

But still showing uncaught error in the screen.
https://prnt.sc/_cD9KTlB94kA

How can I handle Error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried error parameter of react-apollo which is returned on query?

```
   return (
          <div>
          <Query 
            query = {yourQuery}
            variables = {{ 'id':platformId }}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
            if (error) return <div>Error</div>
            value = data.value;
            return (
              <div>
                Your actual html 
                </div>
                )}}
                </Query>
        </div>
```

Or store your received error to state variable and render a modal if error state is not null.

Comment: Yes, that return Error in div. but above that, shows runtimeError. like this. https://prnt.sc/_cD9KTlB94kA